# Why both the pointers show same memory address

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory

```
.....
// Some code
char *options[] = {"\nDATA:","\nSUBJECT:","\nMAILFROM:","\nRCPTO:"};
char *data[3] = {};
```

I am initializing this array of pointers.

But when I try to access each member of array of pointers, I can see that 
options[0]  = data[3] 
   0x40873b = 0x40873b
they both point to same memory location.

Even I have declared 'options' array before the 'data' array.
So How to resolve this.
How can be sure that they are at different memory location and store the contents properly.without overlapping , different data at 2 different location.

Comment: `data[3]` is out of bounds. Array only has indexes 0, 1, and 2.

Comment: Even if this program didn't contain the mentioned undefined behavior bug, you could still end up with two pointers pointing at the same location, since these are pointers to _constant string literals_ which you cannot modify. If you have two such literals in your program, both of them `"hello"` and then point to each literal with an unique pointer, those two literals may still be allocated at the same memory address, because the compiler can tell that they are the same and that they are read-only. This is a compiler optimization called "string pooling".

Answer (score 1):

When you write

```
  char *data[3] = {};
```

the `[3]` means "allocate space for three elements of the array".
It does not mean that you have just created a pointer named
`data[3]` (in fact `data[3]` is not a pointer)
nor that `data[3]` is part of the memory that was
just allocated; rather, the three elements of the memory allocated for
the array are `data[0]`, `data[1]`, and `data[2]`,
which are at the memory locations `data` (0x408738),
`data + 1` (0x408739), and `data + 2` (0x40873a).

If you write

```
  data[3] == options[0]
```

then `data[3]` means whatever is at the memory location `data + 3`,
which is the first thing *after* the last allocated element of `data`.
The compiler happens to have started the memory allocation 
for `options` there, that is, location 0x40873b is where the
first contents of `options` are to be found.

Answer (score 1):

It *looks* like the compiler laid your objects out as follows:

```
          +---+
    data: |   | data[0] 
          +---+
          |   | data[1]
          +---+ 
          |   | data[2] <-- last element of data array
          +---+
options:  |   | options[0], data[3]
          +---+
          |   | options[1], data[4]
          +---+
          |   | options[2], data[5]
          +---+ 
          |   | options[3], data[6] <-- last element of options array
          +---+
```

Your `data` array contains 3 elements, indexed from 0 to 2.  When you access `data[3]`, you're accessing an object one past the end of the `data` array, and it *just so happens* to be the first object of the `options` array.

Note that attempting to read an object one past the end of an array invokes undefined behavior; C doesn't do any bounds checking on array accesses, so doing this won't raise an OutOfBounds exception or anything like that.  In this particular case, you got a reasonable-looking value because the object following the last element of the `data` array has the same type as that element (`char *`).  You could theoretically iterate through the entire `options` array using `data` (as shown above), although that will only "work" in this specific case; if you add another variable or change the code, the compiler could change the order in which things are laid out in memory, and this would suddenly not "work" anymore.

Comment: Everything Said Above is understood . But what's the Solution for this problem called "String Pooling" ?

Comment: @user1421147: The "string pooling" that Lundin described isn't a problem; it's okay to have multiple pointers pointing to the same string literal, since string literals are supposed to be immutable.  However, if you want to have multiple copies of the same string, you'll need to allocate memory for each copy, such as `char *copy = malloc( strlen( str ) + 1); if ( copy ) strcpy( copy, str );`

Comment: What I want is that my string data should not overlap. I want data[3] and options[0] to store different data instead pointing to same memory location.  Can I control in which memory location I can store which data ?

Comment: @user1421147: As it is currently declared, `data[3]` is past the end of your `data` array (3 elements with indices 0, 1, and 2).  You shouldn't be trying to store *anything* there.  Do you mean you don't want `data[2]` and `options[0]` to point to the same memory locations?